# Power BI: Combining cells from a column where given a condition

Tags: calculated-columns, powerbi, dax

I have to perform a task in power BI (DAX) where i have a list of users and their fields of work.
I have to combine all the fields corresponding to every user and find the highest frequency combination.
Below is how I was planning to do it. 
How can i generate the "Expected Result" from the "Sample" file?

```
Sample:
    ID     Value
    a      medicine
    b      automobile
    c      banking
    d      scientist
    a      banking
    a      scientist
    d      banking

Expected Result:
ID      Value Combi
a       medicine|banking|scientist
b       automobile
c       banking
d       scientist|banking
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concatenate values from multiple rows and generate a delimited string by using [CONCATENATEX()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt163697.aspx) DAX function. Then use ADDCOLUMNS and SUMMARIZE to get the desired result.

```
Expected Table =
SUMMARIZE (
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        'Table',
        "Combined Value", CONCATENATEX (
            FILTER (
                SUMMARIZE ( 'Table', 'Table'[ID], [Value] ),
                [ID] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[ID] )
            ),
            'Table'[Value],
            "|"
        )
    ),
    [ID],
    [Combined Value]
)
```

It produces:

[image]

---

**Break down the logic**

The easiest way in my opinion is create a calculated column in your table to generate the combined value column:

```
Combined Value =
CONCATENATEX (
    FILTER (
        SUMMARIZE ( 'Table', 'Table'[ID], [Value] ),
        [ID] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[ID] )
    ),
    'Table'[Value],
    "|"
)
```

Then you can create a summarized table based on your table with the previously created calculated column. To create a calculated table go to the Modeling tab and click the `New Table` icon.

[image]

Use this expression:

```
Resumed Table =
SUMMARIZE ( 'Table', [ID], 'Table'[Combined Value] )
```

You will get a table like this:

[image]

While both methods work just fine, the recommend way to approach this issue is directly from Power Query or from your source.

Let me know if this helps.